# Facebook SDK in Android always calling onCancel

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using Facebook SDK v4.6

I'm trying to setup a GraphAPI request class, it will communicate to Facebook Graph API if AccessToken is available. If not, it will pass an error to my Auth class which will initiate the login process

I'm using the code below to start the login process

`LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity, Arrays.asList("public_profile, user_photos, user_videos"));`

However, the callback `onCancel` is always triggered whenever I do so, resulting to my application not being able to go through the Graph API process

I'm using a Facebook account which is an administrator for the Facebook app. Also the permissions user_photos and user_videos are already approved in Facebook side, so I don't think that's the problem.

Has anyone experienced the same problem?

I've been trying to look here for solution but majority of what I see is to call logout first before logging-in, but is that even correct?

I tried it on device without Facebook app installed, it repeatedly prompt the login dialog even though the user already logged-in previously (i concluded it's to be expected since we logged-out, but I wouldn't want user to repeatedly log-in after access token is expired) or is there no other way?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that,

1. App Id integrated with you app and App Id in Dashboard are the same or not.
2. Facebook user you are trying to login is a **developer** of your app.
   (Because some permissions like '*publish_actions*' will work with
   developer account only not with the test user.)
3. Login function and Graph request should be called with **main thread**
   of your app.

These are the issues i have faced. Still if you can't solve the issue , go through Facebook documentation once again.